Is there a fast/clever way to return a logical vector if elements of a vector are in at least one interval?
Assume you have vector numeric vector x and a data frame df with columns start and stop. Is there a clever way to return a logical vector with length equal to x indicating if x is in at least one interval defined by start or stop ?
The actual case I'm working with has length(x) >> nrow(df). The naïve way to do this would be using a for loop but I was hoping for something more elegant and that runs fast.
 x <- 1:10
df <- data.frame(start = c(0, 4.5, 6), stop = c(1, 5.5, 8.5))
z <- rep(FALSE, length(x))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  z <- z | (df$start[i] <= x & x <= df$stop[i])
}

x[z] # 1 5 6 7 8


Maybe you can use outer like below
> with(df, x[rowMeans(outer(x, start, `>=`) & outer(x, stop, `<=`)) > 0])
[1] 1 5 6 7 8

or, you can use %inrange% from data.table
> library(data.table)

> x[x %inrange% df]
[1] 1 5 6 7 8


I'm working with a large vector ~30M element and 248 MB. This approach is giving me an allocation error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 953.4 Gb".

@noNameTed what about %inrange%? I think that might work for large vector

Did not know about %inrange%, which works terrifically well here, +1!

This is maybe too clever, but does solve your problem. (@ThomasIsCoding's is very similar but slightly more compact ...)
x_gt_start <- outer(x,df$start, ">=")
x_lt_stop <- outer(x,df$stop, "<=")
between <- rowSums(x_gt_start & x_lt_stop) > 0 ## or: apply(..., 1, any)
x[between]

Even faster would be to use Rcpp to write code that looped and short-circuited (i.e., returned TRUE as soon as the condition was met once for a given x, rather than going through all of the comparisons)

I get an error at the first outer. "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 953.4 Gb". I don't have any issue getting this or @ThomasIsCoding's suggestion to work on the toy example. In my actual use case x has ~ 30M elements and is 248 MB. df has a little over 4k rows.

Edit: As user ThomasIsCoding kindly points out, there is data.table::inrange() which is vectorised:
x = seq(10)
df = data.frame(start = c(0, 4.5, 6), stop = c(1, 5.5, 8.5))
x[data.table::inrange(x, df$start, df$stop)]
#> [1] 1 5 6 7 8


You can use %inrange% instead, which is also from data.table

Thank your very much, @ThomasIsCoding, did not know that.

I was thinking about attempting an Rcpp solution but my guess is that it will be more work/less convenient and not much better than the data.table solutions offered here and by @ThomasIsCoding

@BenBolker, I checked Rfast and collapse (related to data.table). As both do not provide an alternative, I conclude there is none.  However, since I read what you have mentioned in your answer w.r.t. Rcpp, I am thinking about a rule based on which the interval to check first is determined. If this exists, it might be the wanted speed-up.

A vectorized function to count the number of intervals of df that contain the element of x. It is faster than data.table::%inrange% for large datasets.
library(data.table)

countrange <- function(x, df) {
  out <- integer(length(x))
  n <- nrow(df)
  setorder(
    data.table(
      i = c(1:length(x), integer(n + n)),
      r = c(x, unlist(df, 0, 0)),
      s = rep.int(c(0L, 1L, -1L), c(length(x), n, n))
    ), r, -s
  )[,s := cumsum(s)][i != 0L, {out[i] <- s; out}]
}

countrange(x, df)
#>  [1] 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0

Demonstrating on a set of potentially overlapping intervals:
x <- runif(10)
df <- data.table(start = sort(runif(1e5)), stop = sort(runif(1e5)))[
  start > stop, `:=`(start = stop, stop = start)
]
countrange(x, df)
#>  [1] 201 320 202  27 169 314 131  92 219   0
x %inrange% df
#>  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE


Benchmarking
We can squeeze a little more speed with collapse::setv.
library(collapse)

countrange2 <- function(x, df) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  m <- length(x)
  out <- integer(m)
  setorder(
    data.table(
      i = setv(integer(n + n + m), 1:m, 1:m),
      r = c(x, unlist(df, 0, 0)),
      s = rep.int(c(0L, 1L, -1L), c(m, n, n))
    ), r, -s
  )[,s := cumsum(s)][i != 0L, {out[i] <- s; out}]
}

While both versions are faster than data.table::%inrange% for large datasets, they also use more memory.
x <- runif(3e7)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sort(runif(8e3)), 4e3, 2, 1))

bench::mark(
  countrange = countrange(x, df),
  countrange2 = countrange2(x, df),
  inrange = x %inrange% df,
  check = FALSE,
  iterations = 10
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 countrange     2.62s    2.71s     0.370    2.26GB    1.55 
#> 2 countrange2    2.56s    2.62s     0.381    2.38GB    1.33 
#> 3 inrange        4.27s    4.57s     0.214  457.54MB    0.128


Be careful when interpreting the mem_alloc result. AFAIK it only accounts for memory managed by R and will not account for any C++ memory allocations used by data.table

Thanks for the reminder. Watching the system memory as I execute the functions, %inrange% definitely uses less memory, but it's closer to half than a quarter.

Here's a solution I came up with using the findInterval() function, which I think (the documentation doesn't specify) uses a binary search algorithm. It assumes that your start and stop times are ordered and your stop times are less than the next start time (it might not require that last assumption; I haven't tested it).
findInterval(x, df$start) == (findInterval(x, df$stop, left.open = T) + 1)

I ran various combinations of benchmarks compared to the countrange() and inrange solution, and my solution tends to range from mid to slowest, but overall they all seem to do pretty good. It's hard to judge from arbitrary benchmarking which is best for OP because the relative performance of each will vary based on the absolute size of the objects, as well as the relative size difference between them. My solution seems to get worse as the length of the vector increases relative to the number of rows in the data table.
However, if the x vector is sorted, then my solution will probably blow the others out of the water; findInterval() is O(n) if x is sorted.
In terms of memory used, it's hard to tell which is best. I'm not aware of any benchmarking package in R that can properly capture C++ memory allocations. Plus, you have to figure out how it scales with the size of the variables. I expect findInterval() to be very memory efficient regardless. I don't know about the other solutions. My advice would be to go with whatever is fastest/fast enough (and maybe easy to read/understand), and if you have memory issues, try another, and so on.

x is typically sorted for my application. When I get time I'll bench mark all the solutions with real data for the benefit of others.

findInterval() is a base R function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html

Whoops, you're right. Started off with some data.table stuff and didn't realize I had wandered out of it. I'll edit that.

@anjama the source shows it is a binary search and also uses the starting range from the previous call as the first try in the next call so you're right, it should be blazingly fast with a sorted x.

Vectorized is fine, but idk if anyone has answered the equivalent of the fun solution for online range queries, i.e. without being able to sort x queries.
Let n = # x queries and m = # ranges.
Sort all 2m endpoints, keeping track of which are left endpoints and which are right endpoints. Build a map by iterating left-to-right, starting the counter from 0, incrementing when encountering a left point and decrementing when encountering a right point. O(m log m) time
To query a point, binary search for the closest endpoint to the left, and see if its value is > 0, meaning it's in a range. O(log m) time
Total time for n queries: O(n log m). If x is sorted, you can simply go through x in ascending order, keeping track of the last endpoint used and incrementing for each x. I believe this would be O(n+m) since you iterate through the whole endpoint list and the queries once.
More explanation: Efficient way to determine if a value falls within multiple ranges
If you need to know which ranges a point is in, use an interval tree.
